# screen keyboard doesn't appear on my 18.04

Tags: gnome, keyboard, gnome-shell, accessibility

In my case screen keyboard appears only on two screens: login/unlock screen and when Ubuntu Software Center prompts for sudo password. In all other cases I don't see screen keyboard. I installed onboard, but is there a way to open explicitly native screen keyboard?

Answer (score 0):

The Native Screen Keyboard in 18.04 seems to be working only with gdm & shell related things and not with GTK related things or apps..

this may be the reason it is working on login/unlock and on authentication prompts only

[image]

from the source https://developer.gnome.org/gok/

> GOK - Gnome Onscreen Keyboard This module is heading towards planned
>   deprecation. It will continue to be supported and API/ABI stable
>   throughout the GNOME 2.x series, but we do not recommend using it in
>   new applications unless you require functionality that has not already
>   been moved elsewhere.

I have just tested GOK in 18.10 and it is working fine in normal apps or in browsers..

[image]

[image]